# Why does centos include extra dependencies in dylib build

Tags: rust

I think it might have something to do with lower level dependencies in my project(openssl, rdkafka), but it does not seem like it from the ldd output

Ubuntu:

[image]

Centos:

[image]

Both built from the same source with

```sh
cargo b --release
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "wrapper-ffi"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
wrapper={path="../wrapper"}

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[features]
cmake-build=["wrapper/cmake-build"]
```

Comment: Note that `ldd` also reports indirect dependencies. In your case I suspect some of those are actually pulled by `libssl` or `libcrypto`. What happens if you use `objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED`?

Comment: @Jmb they are the same on both, except the top 2 ends with .1.1 on ubuntu. I was just wondering why, because the centos build is not importable on ubuntu dotnet core with dllimport. I thought if both have the same target they should be compatible

  NEEDED libssl.so.10
  NEEDED libcrypto.so.10
  NEEDED libz.so.1
  NEEDED libdl.so.2
  NEEDED librt.so.1
  NEEDED libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED libc.so.6
  NEEDED ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
  NEEDED libm.so.6

Comment: This means you can ignore the extra dependencies. However in order to be able to move an executable between machines, it must have the same target _and_ the same direct dependencies. Here, you apparently have different incompatible versions of `libssl` and `libcrypto`.